# Translate C++ code to Haskell

Tags: c++, haskell

I am trying to translate this piece of c++ code to haskell but can't really get my head around it. This is taken from the nim.cpp in http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/cs106b/chapters/07-backtracking-algorithms.pdf .

C++ :

```
const int MAX_MOVE = 3;
const int NO_GOOD_MOVE = -1;

int FindGoodMove(int nCoins) {
    for (int nTaken = 1; nTaken <= MAX_MOVE; nTaken++) {
        if (IsBadPosition(nCoins - nTaken)) return nTaken;
    }
    return NO_GOOD_MOVE;
}

bool IsBadPosition(int nCoins) {
    if (nCoins == 1) return true;
    return FindGoodMove(nCoins) == NO_GOOD_MOVE;
}
```

so far i have done in haskell:

```
findGoodMove nCoins = if isBadPosition (nCoins - nTaken) == True
                        then nTaken
                        else -1
                    where nTaken = 1

isBadPosition nCoins = if nCoins == 1
                        then True
                        else findGoodMove(nCoins) == -1
```

i'm stuck in the for loop part. I would really like some suggestions on how do i translate it to haskell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, I would use Haskell's richer type system to encode for failure in `findGoodMove`, by giving it the type

```
findGoodMove :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

And `isBadPosition` can have the type

```
isBadPosition :: Int -> Bool
```

Next we can move on to implementation.  For this, I'm going to need to import `isNothing` from `Data.Maybe`

```
import Data.Maybe

maxMove :: Int
maxMove = 3

findGoodMove :: Int -> Maybe Int
findGoodMove nCoins = loop 1
    where
        loop nTaken
            | nTaken == maxMove               = Nothing
            | isBadPosition (nCoins - nTaken) = Just nTaken
            | otherwise                       = loop (nTaken + 1)

isBadPosition :: Int -> Bool
isBadPosition 1      = True
isBadPosition nCoins = isNothing $ findGoodMove nCoins
```

So by using `Maybe Int` instead of `Int` for `findGoodMove`, we can encode at the type system level that this function has a single failure mode (i.e. `NO_GOOD_MOVE`), which I would argue makes the intent more clear and ensures that we can't accidentally treat the `NO_GOOD_MOVE` flag as a valid value elsewhere in our code.

For the loop portion, I've defined a recursive function locally called `loop` that starts at `1`, and has 3 branches.  If `nTaken` reaches our max value for moves, we've hit the end of our loop and return `Nothing` (`NO_GOOD_MOVE`).  If that condition is `False`, we then check of `nCoins - nTaken` is a bad position, and if it is we return `Just nTaken`.  If neither of these conditions were `True`, then we perform the loop again with `nTaken + 1`.

For `isBadPosition`, we know that if `nCoins == 1`, it's `True`, so we can use pattern matching to handle that simple case.  Otherwise, we have to know if `findGoodMove nCoins` succeeds, and it only succeeds if it's not `Nothing`.  The `Data.Maybe.isNothing` function is helpful here to quickly check if it's `Nothing` or `Just something`, so it makes this case easy as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
max_move = 3
no_good_move = -1

findGoodMove nCoins = findGoodMoveStep nCoins 1

findGoodMoveStep nCoins nTaken = if nTaken> max_move
                        then no_good_move
                        else if isBadPosition (nCoins - nTaken) == True
                        then nTaken
                        else findGoodMoveStep nCoins nTaken+1


isBadPosition nCoins = if nCoins == 1
                        then True
                        else findGoodMove(nCoins) == no_good_move
```

Comment: ah ok, I am move versed in Scala, so didn't know that

Comment: This is more of a "transliteration" than a translation.  A good starting place at least.

Comment: thanks. :D i think in "else findGoodMove nCoins nTaken+1 " u meant findGoodMoveStep ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the `loop` function as in @bheklilr 's answer, you can use a [list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension), which is a powerful tool in the Haskell language. Then you can use pattern matching to take the right choice of `nTaken`.

```
maxMove :: Int
maxMove = 3

findGoodMove :: Int -> Maybe Int
findGoodMove nCoins =
  let choices = [nTaken | nTaken <- [1..maxMove], isBadPosition (nCoins - nTaken)]
  in case choices of
    [] -> Nothing
    (nTaken:_) -> Just nTaken

isBadPosition :: Int -> Bool
isBadPosition 1 = True
isBadPosition nCoins = findGoodMove nCoins == Nothing
```

Since Haskell is lazy. The list `choices` won't be fully constructed. It will stop once it found the first valid `nTaken`. So the time complexity of function `findGoodMove` is the same as the C++ version.